# JSR223 Pre-Processor Generate a Value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a situation where I am trying to figure out how to get a value that is generated dynamically within the web application. It's used in pretty much almost every request in the workflow I have been using.

I notice that it is created based on a javascript code within a function that goes along the lines of something like

```js
function getbrowserSecurityPrint() {
 var choices = {
   excludes: {
     'random1' = true,
     'random2' = true,
     'random3' = true,
     'random4' = true,
     'random5' = true,
     'random6' = true,
 }
};

var materials = {};
SecurityPrint2.get(options,functions(materials){
  var values = materials.map(functions(materials) {
   return materials.value; 
}};

SecurityPrintToken = SecurityPrint2.x64hash128(values.join(''), 31);
brand.d.browserSecurityPrint = '{g1}' + SecurityPrintToken;
});
if (!brand.d.ServerProxy.isDestinationLocal()){
  getbrowserSecurityPrint(); 
}
function setSecurityPrint () {
  getbrowserSecurityPrint();
}
function setbrowserSecurityPrint() {
 var element = document.getElementById("GOP");
 if (element != null) {
   document.getElementByID("GOP").value = brand.d.browserSecurityPrint;};
```

Essentially I want the value GOP, but I can't find it anywhere to correlate it since I assume it is being generated within the source code.

I tried using the JSR223 pre-processor, but I am stuck as I don't know how to use it to achieve what I want

Answer (score 0):

1. The value of `GOP` (whatever it is) you can check using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) by running the following code in the console:

   ```
   document.getElementById("GOP")
   ```

   if it's not there - assume that it is [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null)

   In case the value is there you can get it using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)
2. With regards to "using" the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) there are 2 options:

   - if you use `javascript` language you can try copying and pasting this `getbrowserSecurityPrint()` function however JMeter is not a browser, you won't have access to basic objects like [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) or [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) or the aforementioned `GOP` element so you will need to come up with alternative solutions
   - if you use `groovy` language (which is the [recommended option](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)) you will have to re-implement `getbrowserSecurityPrint()` function totally in Groovy. The same restrictions as for `javascript` apply though

Currently we cannot help you because you provided an incomplete code and for example  we don't know who is `SecurityPrint2 guy. I can only suggest using [JavaScript debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) and inspect the function step by step understanding what it is doing and whether it's possible and how you can replicate it in Groovy.